# Getting large photo with additional fields - Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, get

So this is how I'm retrieving Facebook friends and profile picture right now:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{{user_id}}/?fields=picture,friends&access_token={{app_id}}|{{app_secret}}`

However, the photo I get with it is small and the only way to get a large photo is:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{{user_id}}/picture?type=large&access_token={{app_id}}|{{app_secret}}`

So now I have to make two get requests; one for a large photo, and one to get the friends. I want to achieve both in one request. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call

```
/{user_id}?fields=id,name,friends,picture.type(large)&access_token={access_token}
```

should do what you desire.